# Wordpress current user is 'invalid' when on http instead of https

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site on wordpress that works on both http and https, but, when the user logs it obviously uses https.

What i've noticed is that after i've logged in, if i access any page using http the wp_get_current_user() function returns a private user with ID=0. I can also see that this is the value on the global $current_user field. But, i can still access most of the functionality in my website that requires the user to be logged in, including the account page.

If i simply change back to https wp_get_current_user() returns the correct value.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You may want to add a redirect rule on your httpd server (nginx/apache) to redirect all http requests to https. That will solve your problem and is the right thing to do security wise.

Comment: `0` is not an actual user id, it means there _is_ no user. Likely an issue with session cookie parameters. _“I have a site on wordpress that works on both http and https”_ - that is what you should actually fix ... who benefits from your site being accessible using HTTP as well? Likely no one, so you should set up your rewriting to redirect any request made for an HTTP URL to the HTTPS version to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **get_userdata** function instead of **wp_current_user()**

[**get_userdata Codex**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)